# DSNURWBG - INPUT FIELD ffffff NOT ENTIRELY WITHIN INPUT RECORD

Tags: db2, load, mainframe, jcl, db2-zos

I am trying to load a file to a DB2 table and getting following error:

INPUT FIELD ffffffff NOT ENTIRELY WITHIN INPUT RECORD

can anyone pls suggest what is going wrong.

Comment: Is this the message you are receiving ?  DSNU335I   csect-name INPUT FIELD 'ffffffff' NOT ENTIRELY WITHIN INPUT RECORD  If so, I would include the message ID DSNU335I in the title as it is more likely that other posters will be searching that field.

Comment: Nothing you show is JCL so why the JCL tag? Are you really running under MVS and not ZOS?

Comment: @Hogstrom, added message id to the title.

Comment: @NicC, this is ran on Z/OS, corrected the tag. also posting the load step used in the JCL.

Comment: It would be great to know what record format are you using for your input dataset? If you are using VB then your UPDATE_ID value ends at position 115, However you are declaring that UPDATE_ID is a CHAR (not a varchar) so your value must be 10 characters long, not less.

Comment: @VadimKo UPDATE_ID is declared as a char of length 10 in the table and the control card used to load the data into the table. Record format of the input file is VB.

Comment: The length of your UPDATE_ID value is 7 symbols "CONVERT"  if you want to add it to DB2 as a CHAR, you must add 3 more symbols. 
or you can alter table column from CHAR to VARCHAR if you are planing to use dynamic amount of symbols in future.

Comment: @VadimKo, ok thank you so much, I will try and share the results as soon as I can.

Comment: @VadimKo, I changed the input data as suggested and it worked. thank you so much for your help.

Comment: What happened to the whole question.  It was well formatted and helpful.  What seems to be left is not very informative and the answers don't have a reference

Answer (score 1):

In this example you have two identical columns CREATE_ID and UPDATE_ID both are CHAR(10), However CREATE_ID is in the middle of the dataset, and when you are reading the input file you end up with "CONVERT   "  value, with 3 spaces. in total 10 symbols.

When you are reading UPDATE_ID you end up with "CONVERT" value in total 7 symbols, therefore your load process fails. If you want to use CHAR(10) you must provide an input that is 10 symbols length.

In your case it happens because you are using RECFM=VB ( virtual block ) dataset, that dynamicaly sets the (LRECL) length of each record. In your case the length of the record is set to 115.

You have few options here:

1. if you are planing to use dynamic amount of characters in your
   UPDATE_ID column, then you should change your column to VARCHAR. (i would go for this one)
2. Or you can add 3 more symbols to "CONVERT" value, and use it as CHAR
3. Or you can use input file with RECFM=FB and LRECL=118, in this case it will automatically fill last 3 symbols as spaces.